# Combining makefile targets into a more reusable target

Tags: makefile

My Makefile has the following macros defined:

```
# Output location
OUT_DIR = Build

# Source location
SOURCE_DIR = Src

# Complete list of source files to be compiled
SOURCES  = $(SOURCE_DIR)/main.c
SOURCES += $(SOURCE_DIR)/startup.s
SOURCES += System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f4xx.c

# Separate out .c and .s source files
C_SOURCES = $(filter %.c, $(SOURCES))
ASM_SOURCES = $(filter %.s, $(SOURCES))

# Rename .c to .o, and replace the path with $(OUT_DIR)/
# For example Src/main.c becomes Build/main.o
OBJECTS  = $(addprefix $(OUT_DIR)/, $(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(OUT_DIR)/, $(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
```

...and I have the following target that's bugging me a bit:

```
$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
    @echo

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/%.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
    @echo
```

Is there a way I can have the target defined one, without having to specify the path? Seems like too much repetition...

The targets both work fine, but I just feel that it's unnecessary to repeat targets like this.

Comment: Will using VPATH like this help: `VPATH = Src : System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Canned Recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) which contains the body of the recipe and use that in each rule but you can't combine rules that have such *wildly* different prerequisite patterns.

```
define JVN_COMPILE
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
    @echo
endef

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(JVN_COMPILE)

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/%.c
    $(JVN_COMPILE)
```

or, set VPATH and do the following:

```
VPATH = Src:System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates

define JVN_COMPILE
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$(notdir $@)
    @echo
endef

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(JVN_COMPILE)
```

Comment: This helps and it works, but I can't understand why a sample I'm referring to simply has a rule like `%.o: %.c` and the whole thing works, despite the basepath being different on the source files?

Comment: Because the input and output directories on those files is quite likely the same where yours are not. That's the difference. The only part of the target/prerequisite that can vary is what the `%` matches (or, in unison, the directories of those files when the target doesn't specify any directory components). The sample could also be using `VPATH`/`vpath` to help make find sources in alternate directories (to "pretend" the directories are specified in the prerequisite list.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Etan Reisner, there's a vpath defined. I'll read some docs to see if I can use vpath to fix?

Comment: Booyah! @Etan, I used your Canned Recipe approach, thanks for that, and combined that with setting vpath as follows `VPATH = Src:System/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates`